# Combine raw query with resource index method

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following which queries the `container_slots` table and returns all  remaining unoccupied slots.

```
    return DB::table('container_slots')
->where('occupied', false)
->join('plate_containers','container_slots.plate_container_id', '=', 'plate_containers.id')
->select('plate_containers.name AS Container', DB::raw('count(container_slots.slot) as no_of_slots'))
->groupBy('plate_container_id')->get();
```

This works just fine.

returns

```
    [
  {
    "Container": "Test container #1",
    "no_of_slots": 3
  }
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to somewho combine this with the index() method being called upon as soon as a user visits a page.

```
    public function index()
{
    $plateContainers = PlateContainer::paginate(25);

    return response()->success($plateContainers);
}
```

which returns this.

```
    {
  "success": {
    "total": 2,
    "per_page": 25,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 51,
        "name": "Test container #1",
        "description": null,
        "number_of_slots": 5,
        "material": "Glass",
        "comment": null,
        "plate_container_type_id": 51,
        "storage_location_id": 13,
        "equipment_status_code_id": 17,
        "created_by": 1,
        "created_at": "2016-12-30 10:24:08",
        "updated_at": "2017-01-04 15:43:05",
        "updated_by": 1

      },
      {
        "id": 52,
        "name": "Test container #2",
        "description": null,
        "number_of_slots": null,
        "material": "glass",
        "comment": null,
        "plate_container_type_id": 51,
        "storage_location_id": 7,
        "equipment_status_code_id": 17,
        "created_by": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-01-04 09:29:15",
        "updated_at": "2017-01-04 09:38:51",
        "updated_by": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Somewhere in the `data` array I would like to have a key and value (for each object) of the query above. Would that be possible? 
I have tried to achieve this doing eager loading, but wasn't able to get it right.

A little more information.

**PlateContainer** model

```
public function containerSlots()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ContainerSlot');
}
```

**ContainerSlot** model

```
public function plateContainer()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PlateContainer');
}
```

Hopefully you get the idea. Thanks for your time.

**Update #1**: Based on answer below.

I gave the suggested method a try and this is what it returned.

```
    "data": [
  {
    "id": 51,
    "name": "Test container #1",
    "description": null,
    "number_of_slots": 5,
    "material": "Glass",
    "comment": null,
    "plate_container_type_id": 51,
    "storage_location_id": 13,
    "equipment_status_code_id": 17,
    "created_by": 1,
    "created_at": "2016-12-30 10:24:08",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-04 15:43:05",
    "updated_by": 1,
    "my_count": [
      {
        "Container": "Test container #1",
        "no_of_slots": 4
      },
      {
        "Container": "Test container #3",
        "no_of_slots": 3
      }
    ],
```

So almost there. Only this is returning all the unoccupied slots per `PlateContainer` instance.  The idea is to get **only** the unoccupied slots of that particular `plate container`. So in this case I only need the `Test Container #1` unoccupied slots. The `Test Container #3` should be the in the next instance. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

With eager loading should work fine.

```
$plateContainers = PlateContainer::with('ContainerSlot')->paginate(25);
```

That would append a ContainerSlots attribute into every PlateContainer.

If you only want to have that count query in every PlateContainer model, you could use mutators:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators

The idea would be to set the $appends property into your model and to define a custom attribute getter:

```
$appends = ['my_count'];

public function getMyCountAttribute() 
{
    return; //return your DB query here
}
```

If you only want that count in that index action, maybe you should just return your query there instead of PlateContainer::paginate();

Hope this helps, feel free to comment if not!

Comment: I have updated the post. Would you have a look. Thanks!